# How to get the exact size of a Redshift Cluster?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I used the below Query on a REDSHIFT CLUSTER

```
SELECT sum("size") from svv_table_info ;
```

Output : 321,563,805 (in MB) [ this is the Disk Space consumed ]

---

And Using another query I got the MAX DISK CAPACITY of the REDSHIFT CLUSTER by below query

```
SELECT SUM(capacity) AS total   FROM   stv_partitions   WHERE  part_begin = 0 ;
```

Output: 400,691,024 (in MB) [ max Disk capacity]

---

NOTE: svv_table_info and stv_partitions are both SYSTEM TABLES

But when I am validating the same by checking Disk Used by REDSHIFT CLUSTER on AWS REDSHIFT CONSOLE

It is showing

> total size is 288TB in cluster - 100.00% (288.00 of 288 TB used)

**Q1) Why is the REDSHIFT CONSOLE showing 288 TB as 100% where as the above query is showing 400,691,024 (in MB) as max capacity?**

**Q2) Why is it not the same on both ? what is the reason ? Is there any other way to get the exact size of Cluster/Table ?**